# OpenVPN client connection errors with "Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway"

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to a private internet access vpn with openvpn. When I try to connect I get the following output:

```
Wed Dec  5 19:10:37 2018 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  5 2018
Wed Dec  5 19:10:37 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: xxxxxxx
Enter Auth Password: **********
Wed Dec  5 19:10:46 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]107.182.231.27:1198
Wed Dec  5 19:10:46 2018 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed Dec  5 19:10:46 2018 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]107.182.231.27:1198
Wed Dec  5 19:10:46 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Dec  5 19:10:46 2018 [bb1f148439dd776739a59e0d0943706f] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]107.182.231.27:1198
Wed Dec  5 19:10:47 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Dec  5 19:10:47 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Wed Dec  5 19:10:47 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Dec  5 19:10:47 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.62.10.6 peer 10.62.10.5
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

Here is the vpn config file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote us-newyorkcity.privateinternetaccess.com 1198
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server

auth-user-pass

compress
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
<crl-verify>
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----
-----END X509 CRL-----
</crl-verify>

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

disable-occ
```

Here is my `ip route`:

```
default via 213.239.213.193 dev enp2s0 proto static onlink 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```